# Android Studio intermittent ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-build

I've already read serveral Q&A's from SO and did not found a solution.

My problem is: I run my app from AndroidStudio and get the error bellow, then I run `gradlew clean installDebug` and code works just fine (outside AS, with NO changes).

I did NOT forgot to include my activity into AndroidManifest.

```
10-13 13:36:18.261    1457-1457/my.package E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.package, PID: 1457
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.activity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package-1, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.activity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package-1, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.12 and this is reproducible with real devices and emulator (Genymotion).

**EDIT**
I've tried both "full path" and "class name only" into my AndroidManifest file to declare activities. And it still doesn't explain (IMHO) why it works via command line with gradle.

Comment: How are you including your activity on the manifest? Full package path?

Comment: Did you run Build->Clean Project in the menu in AS? Might be that AS is using the gradle wrapper (gradlew) and it's a different instance of gradle. I would also stop all the gradle daemons ("gradle --stop" and "./gradlew --stop" in the project dir from the shell - mac,lunux - don't know for win)

Comment: If you have something that works from the command line and not from Android Studio, often it's because you've got something in your build scripts that implicitly relies on the working directory being set to the project root -- Android Studio doesn't do this when it builds. The solution is to never use fully relative paths in your build scripts.

Comment: @skipper3k I did executed "Clean Project" and did not solved the problem. I'll test your tip (gradle stop) - Thanks!

Comment: @ScottBarta my gradle script is pretty simple and similar to the original generated by AS. I'll take a look again to check if your suggestion solves the problem - Thanks!